# Firestore security rules and custom claims - can uses overwrite them?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to use custom claims in my Firestore security rules but I read that they can apparently be overwritten by users:

> However, if the same custom user claims are defined on a user signed
>   in via custom authentication, the overlapping claims defined in the
>   custom token have higher priority and always overwrite the custom user
>   claims defined on a user via this API.
>   [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims][1]

Which defeats the purpose, so I guess I must be missing something?

EDIT: moved extra question to another post

Comment: Please edit the question to limit yourself to a single question. Posts with multiple questions are considered "off topic" for Stack Overflow.  Feel free to post different questions separately.

Comment: Answered the first question below. As Doug already commented: please post the other question in a separate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user cannot set custom claims on their own account. The only way to set custom claims on a user profile is through the Admin SDK, which requires that you have access to the *project credentials* of the Firebase project, something only collaborators on that project do.